# JCEKS keystore as resource in War

Tags: java, maven, war, keystore

I have a JCEKS keystore that I am loading from a war file as a resource.  I am using the keystore to store secret keys for AES encryption.  The keystore works fine when I attempt to read from it in a canned project where I open the file directly.  When I access the keystore as a resource, however, I am getting the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.JceKeyStore.engineLoad(DashoA13*..)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1185)
```

After doing a little Googling this makes me believe that the passwords I am using are incorrect, but after verifying that they are right I am still getting the error.  Here is where I am attempting to load in the keystore data.

```
public class AegisDataStoreFactory {
    ...
    static {
        InputStream in = null;
        try{
            final Configuration conf = Configuration.getConfiguration();
            final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
            in = AegisDataStoreFactory.class.getResourceAsStream(KEYSTORE);
            final String password = conf.getProp("keyStorePassword").trim();
            ks.load(in, password.toCharArray());
            ...
        } finally {
            if(in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The program fails on the load with the IOException.  I am at a loss here.  It works fine when I am not loading it from within a war.  I am using Maven to generate the war file.

Any thoughts?

Edit:
I figured out what was happening.  I use Maven for my build and during the build I had filtering enabled for resource files.  Up to this point I didn't have any binary files in my resources directory (I only had some property files that I wanted to have the filtering on).  Once I excluded the keystore from the filtering, but still made sure that the keystore was moved, it worked.

Comment: How did you verify that the keystore password was correct (keytool, openssl)? Did you debug and ensure that the password string in your code is in fact what you think it should be?

Comment: Yes I used keytool, as well as making a standalone java project in eclipse and I was able to get the keystore to load.

Comment: You should write up your solution (which definitely looks like a correct one to me) as an answer to your question and mark it as correct. You don't get a bonus to reputation (unless someone votes it up) but it does make it possible for others to discover the answer.

Comment: Also, after you've done that you should adjust the _question_ to mention properly that you're using Maven to do the WAR assembly. After  all, that turns out to be critical here…

Comment: I will be sure to do that once the 8 hour cool down period for me is over.

Comment: Cool - glad you got it resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was happening. I use Maven for my build and during the build I had filtering enabled for resource files. Up to this point I didn't have any binary files in my resources directory (I only had some property files that I wanted to have the filtering on). Once I excluded the keystore from the filtering, but still made sure that the keystore was moved, it worked.  Here is my initial pom file:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Here is what I updated my pom file to. (My keystore has the file extension .ks)

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.ks</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.ks</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: Hi Pat, How did you do with testing using https://localhost:8080? Does it work for you? Thanks!